# Как добавить margin или padding для ImageView в JavaFX с помощью кода (не FXML)?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, padding, margin

Я хочу добавить белый бордюр вокруг ImageView.

Одним из решений является использование Button.

[image: Группа кнопок]

Попробовал использовать StackPane:

```
StackPane stackPaneforImageActivity = new StackPane();

    Image activityImage = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    ImageView imv = new ImageView(activityImage);

    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(stackPaneforImageActivity);

    stackPaneforImageActivity.getChildren().add(imv);

    stackPaneforImageActivity.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    stackPaneforImageActivity.setStyle("-fx-border-color:white;-fx-background-color: black;");

    imv.setFitHeight(30);
    imv.setFitWidth(30);

newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(imv);
```

[image: Использование StackPane]

Но в результате изображение выходит за пределы StackPane.

По какой причине это происходит?

Есть ли другой вариант вокруг изображения сделать бордюр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина - последняя строка кода, которую я не сразу заметил.

Получается, что ImageView я добавил в макет два раза. Один раз в StackPane:

```
stackPaneforImageActivity.getChildren().add(imv);
```

и второй раз в HBox:

```
newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(imv);
```

Сработала только последняя строчка.

Непонятно почему нет изображения и в StackPane.

Окончательный вариант кода выглядит так:

```
Image activityImage = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            ImageView imv = new ImageView(activityImage);

        StackPane stackPaneforImageActivity = new StackPane();

        stackPaneforImageActivity.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(stackPaneforImageActivity);

        stackPaneforImageActivity.getChildren().add(imv);

        stackPaneforImageActivity.setPadding(new Insets(0,10,0,10));

        stackPaneforImageActivity.setStyle("-fx-border-color:white;-fx-background-color: black;");

        imv.setFitHeight(30);
        imv.setFitWidth(30);
```

[image: Белый бордюр вокруг изображения добавлен.]